# How to add multiple conditions to if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm still new to python and am working on a program that is going fairly well. However, if-statements are my greatest weakness.
I want to edit an if-statement.

it now says:

```
  # add 50 cents if paying with credit card
  if info.payment == UIPayment.CreditCard:
        price += 0.50
```

but it needs to say something along:

```
if payment == creditcard (but value of payment is not 0):
price += 0.50
```

If the value of payment is 0, there is no need to "price += 0.50"

Comment: This is what "and", "or" and "not" are for. Use "and" instead of "but".

Comment: Here's a good intro to [compound booleans with logical operators](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/ap-computer-science-principles/programming-101/boolean-logic/a/compound-booleans-with-logical-operators). Note that it uses JavaScript but explains the basic idea well (and has links for similar code in Python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logical operators `and` and `or` to combine conditions.

```
if payment == creditcard and price != 0:
    price += 0.50
```

Comment: I think "value of payment is not 0" means `if payment and payment == creditcard`. Not an extra `value` variable.

Comment: @tdelaney I think `payment` is payment type (e.g. PayPal or credit card), not the value of it.